# Angular 4 - Custom validator with dynamic parameter value

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, typescript

I have written a custom validator that checks if a date is above a certain minimum date.

the code looks like this:

```
export function validateMinDate(min: Date): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {

        if (c == null || c.value == null)
            return null;

        let isValid = c.value >= min;
        if (isValid) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return {
                validateMinDate: {
                    valid: false
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

I initate my form like this

```
    this.definitionForm = this.fb.group({            
        "from": [this.details.From, Validators.required],
        "to": [this.details.To, [Validators.required, validateMinDate(this.details.From)]]
    });
```

I can see that the validator is being applied, but when I `console.log()` my min value in the validator I can see that it equal `null`.

`this.details.From` starts at null when I initiate the form, so I assume the parameter is not dynamic and just takes the value when the form is being set?

How can I make sure the min date is being updated when a users picks a from date, and thus changes the value of `this.details.From`?

Comment: You could try to use a the validator as a directive and inject a service which you can update with the newest values of this.details.From.

Comment: what you have to do is to watch the `From` Date , in every change u have to reset the validator to the control `to` , are you using a Date picker ? or just a simple input. ?

Answer (score 16):

@Nicolas Validator takes value only once it does not look for it changes. So we can change parameters value dynamically by assigning new validator on value changes. In your case you can do in this way:

```
 onChanges(){
   var self=this;
    this.definitionForm.get('from').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
     this.from=val;
     this.definitionForm.controls['to'].
     setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
     TimeValidators.isTimeAfter(this.from)]));
})}
```

Here i created a separate custom validator for comparing the time. You can either use this or modify yours

```
import { FormControl, Validators,ValidatorFn, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

export class TimeValidators extends Validators{

  static isTimeBefore(timeStr : string): ValidatorFn{
    return(c: AbstractControl): {[key:string]: boolean} | null => {
      if(c.value!==undefined && (isNaN(c.value)) || c.value > timeStr || c.value== timeStr){
        return {
          'isTimeBefore':true
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
  static isTimeAfter(timeStr : string): ValidatorFn{
    return(c: AbstractControl): {[key:string]: boolean} | null => {
      if(c.value!==undefined && (isNaN(c.value)) && (c.value < timeStr || c.value == timeStr)){
        return {
          'isTimeAfter':true
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Call `onChanges()` function after you initialize your `definitionForm FormGroup`.

Answer (score 13):

You can modify your custom validator to take function as parameter like

```
export function validateMinDate(min: DateFunc): ValidatorFn {
return (c: AbstractControl) => {

    if (c == null || c.value == null)
        return null;

    let isValid = c.value >= min();
    if (isValid) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return {
            validateMinDate: {
                valid: false
            }
        };
    }
};
```

and initiate the form like this

```
 this.definitionForm = this.fb.group({            
    ...
    "to": [this.details.To, [Validators.required, validateMinDate(() => this.details.From)]]
});
```

the `DateFunc` is just a type that you can create like

```
export interface DateFunc{
 (): Date
}
```

and expect `this.details.From` to return value of type `Date`

Comment: Best answer IMO.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Instead of the `DateFunc` interface you could also just use `() => Date` as the parameter type.

Answer (score 5):

How I see it, would be to apply the validator on the form group, or if you have a large form, I suggest you create a nested group for `from` and `to` and apply the validator on that, since otherwise this custom validator would be fired whenever any changes happen to form. So it would mean to update the validator and formgroup to such:

```
this.definitionForm = this.fb.group({            
  "from": [this.details.From, Validators.required],
  "to": [this.details.To, [Validators.required]]
}, {validator: validateMinDate()});

export function validateMinDate(): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {
      if(c) {
        let isValid = c.get('to').value >= c.get('from').value;
        if (isValid) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return {validateMinDate: true};
        }
      }
    };
}
```

Of course there are other options as well, such as listening for change event and then do the check of the dates, if not valid, use `setErrors` on form.

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki My answer begins with "How I see it..." meaning this is how I would modify the custom validator to look like.

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki I guess we then just have to agree to disagree :) It solves the underlying problem, i.e to check that `to` date is not smaller than `from` date.

Comment: Have solved my problem but now I don't know how to present an error message :/

Comment: @JéssicaMachado you can i.e. control.getError('validateMinDate') and check if you have true back.. with that flag you can show/hide your error-text in template. (control can be either your formgroup or a single formcontrol)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the given answers, at least in Angular 6 you can pass the component as ValidatorFn argument, so you can use its properties at runtime to validate your form control.
Here is a working example:

Component declarations:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './create-application.component.html'
})
export class CreateApplicationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   
    viewMode: ViewMode;
    application: Application;
    form: FormGroup;
    enterprisesData: any[] = [];
```

Form:

```
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: new FormControl(
            { 
                value: (this.viewMode === ViewMode.CONSULT || this.viewMode === ViewMode.EDIT) ? this.application.name : '', 
                disabled: (this.viewMode === ViewMode.CONSULT || this.viewMode === ViewMode.EDIT) 
            }, 
            { 
                validators: [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(80) ], 
                updateOn: 'blur' 
            }
        ),
        area: new FormControl(
            {
                value: (this.viewMode === ViewMode.CONSULT || this.viewMode === ViewMode.EDIT) ? this.application.area : '',
                disabled: (this.viewMode === ViewMode.CONSULT) 
            }, 
            {
                validators: [ Validators.required ]
            }        
        ),
        country: new FormControl(
            {
                value: '',
                disabled: (this.viewMode === ViewMode.CONSULT)
            }, 
            {
                validators: [ applicationCountryEnterprisesValidator(this) ]
            }
        )
    });
```

ValidatorFn:

```
export function applicationCountryEnterprisesValidator(component: CreateApplicationComponent): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
        return (component.enterprisesData && component.enterprisesData.length > 0) ? null : { noEnterprisesSelected: true };
    };
}
```