# Angular creating custom reactive form validator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

I created simple ValidatorFn function:

```
  requiredArrayLength(length: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (length >= 1) {
        return null;
      }
      else
        return { 'requiredArrayLength': true };
    }
  }
```

and i'm trying use this by my formControl:

```
  createClientForm = new FormGroup({
    redirectUris: new FormControl(null, [this.requiredArrayLength(this.redirectUris.length)]),
    allowedScopes: new FormControl(null, [this.requiredArrayLength(this.allowedScopes.length)]),
    postLogoutUris: new FormControl(null, [this.requiredArrayLength(this.postLogoutUris.length)])
  });
```

These arrays aren't empty, because their values are successfully displayed in my mat-chip-list:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" color="accent" class="field">
                <mat-label>Redirect URIs</mat-label>
                <mat-chip-list #redirectUrisList formControlName="redirectUris">
                    <mat-chip class="chip" *ngFor="let redirectUri of redirectUris"
                        (removed)="remove(redirectUri, 'redirectUri')">
                        {{redirectUri}}
                        <button matChipRemove>
                            <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </mat-chip>
                    <input placeholder="New redirect uri..." [matChipInputFor]="redirectUrisList"
                        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
                        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, 'redirectUri')">
                </mat-chip-list>
            </mat-form-field>
```

The problem is that my formControl is always wrong, but when I assign formControlName to input instead of mat-chip-list, it's always without wrongs
even when there are no items in the list.

Comment: Before `if (length >= 1)` block, add `console.log(length)` and see what gets printed. If `this.redirectUris` was an empty array when FormControl was created, then you will get `length` as 0.

Comment: Yes, it's 0. So I must update reference after add/remove element to this.redirectUris, yes?

Comment: See if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66345818/9471852) helps

Comment: I do this: https://pastebin.com/AW6naSa0 and it's still same effect. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the validator, but how the form controls are being used. There are already couple of questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53483323/9471852, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56492325/9471852. See if those are helpful in your case, else please share a Stackblitz minimal reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: Ok. I did all like that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-gywxjz, but now I'm having problem with ValidatorFn. It looks like that: https://pastebin.com/BZGzqfGi. 'Test' is always logging when add/remove mat-chip, but 'test2' is never logging. Why?

Comment: Ohh. My big fault! It will look like this: https://pastebin.com/NRyxyX8Z, I was using ValidatorFn, because there was error without this. But now I know, this error was causing by FormControl in argument, instead of AbstractControl. Thanks you! Very thanks!